# How to convert List<Tuple<int, int>> to Dictionary<int, List<int>>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have duplicate keys with different values and I want to convert it to a dictionary with 1 key and its values.

The next example will explain best what I mean:

```
var tup = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
tup.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
tup.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));

var dic = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

What is an elegant way to convert the tup to dic?

I managed to do this with `foreach` but would like to write it in LINQ.

```
foreach (var item in tup)
{
    if (dic.ContainsKey(item.Item1))
    {
        dic[item.Item1].Add(item.Item2);
    }
    else
    {
        dic.Add(item.Item1, new List<int> { item.Item2 });
    }
}
```

Comment: `.ToDictionary(...)`

Comment: @WiktorZychla Tried... But how to make the value be List?

Comment: First group by the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var list = tup.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
              .ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Key, 
                    x => x.Select(y => y.Item2).ToList());
```

First, we group by `GroupBy` item 1. This should be obvious enough.

Then, we call `ToDictionary` and pass in a `keySelector` and an `elementSelector`. They select the key and value respectively, given an `IGrouping<int, Tuple<int, int>>`.

For reference, [this particular overload of `ToDictionary` is used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx).

Alternatively, as Iridium has said in the comments, this works as well:

```
var list = tup.GroupBy(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

[This overload of `GroupBy` allows you to select 2 things!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can shorten this somewhat by using another overload of `GroupBy`, that specifies an "element selector", allowing the `Select` to be removed: `tup.GroupBy(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());`

Answer (score 4):

You first need to group by the first tuple element in order to find all elements that have the same key in the dictionary. And then just collect the second tuple elements and make a list out of it:

```
tup.GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(t => t.Item2).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` to resolve this problem, like:

```
var tup = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
tup.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1));
tup.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2));

var dic = tup
         .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, tuples => tuples.Select(x => x.Item2).ToList());
```

BTW, in some cases you can use `NameValueCollection`, but this is not save your target type, for example

```
var nvc = tup.Aggregate(new NameValueCollection(),
  (seed, current) =>
  {
    seed.Add(current.Item1.ToString(), current.Item2.ToString());
    return seed;
  });

foreach (var item in nvc)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Key = {item} Value = {nvc[item.ToString()]}");
}
```